# best way to reverse bytes in an int in java

Tags: java

What's the best way to reverse the order of the 4 bytes in an int in java??

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use [`Integer.reverseBytes`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#reverseBytes%28int%29):

```
int numBytesReversed = Integer.reverseBytes(num);
```

There's also [`Integer.reverse`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#reverse%28int%29) that reverses every bit of an `int`

```
int numBitsReversed = Integer.reverse(num);
```

#### `java.lang.Integer` API links

- [`public static int reverseBytes(int i)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#reverseBytes%28int%29)

  - Returns the value obtained by reversing the order of the bytes in the two's complement representation of the specified int value.
- [`public static int reverse(int i)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#reverse%28int%29)

  - Returns the value obtained by reversing the order of the bits in the two's complement binary representation of the specified int  value.

---

#### Solution for other primitive types

There are also some `Long`, `Character`, and `Short` version of the above methods, but some are notably missing, e.g. `Byte.reverse`. You can still do things like these:

```
byte bitsRev = (byte) (Integer.reverse(aByte) >>> (Integer.SIZE - Byte.SIZE));
```

The above reverses the bits of `byte aByte` by promoting it to an `int` and reversing that, and then shifting to the right by the appropriate distance, and finally casting it back to `byte`.

If you want to manipulate the bits of a `float` or a `double`, there are [`Float.floatToIntBits`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToIntBits%28float%29) and [`Double.doubleToLongBits`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits%28double%29) that you can use.

#### See also

- [Wikipedia/Bitwise operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)
- [Bit twiddling hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that polygenelubricants's answer is the best one. But just before I hit that, I had the following:

```
int reverse(int a){
   int r = 0x0FF & a;
   r <<= 8; a >>= 8;
   r |= 0x0FF & a;
   r <<= 8; a >>= 8;
   r |= 0x0FF & a;
   r <<= 8; a >>= 8;
   r |= 0x0FF & a;
   return r;
}
```

shifting the input right, the output left by 8 bits each time and OR'ing the least significant byte to the result.